# Database is showing but collections is not showing in Mongo Compass Enterprise Version

Tags: mongodb, collections

I have created a collection level read-Only role and user in Mongo Enterprise Server v3.4. Here is the user defined role:

```
db.createRole(
{role: "Dummyrole","privileges" : [
                {
                        "resource" : {
                                "db" : "myDb1",
                                "collection" : "myCol1"
                        },
                        "actions" : [
                                "collStats",
                                "dbHash",
                                "dbStats",
                                "find",
                                "killCursors",
                                "listCollections",
                                "listIndexes",
                                "planCacheRead"
                        ]
                }
        ]    , roles: []});
```

Even though I can able to see Database myDb1 and myCol1 in Mongo Compass Community version, I cannot able to see collections in any of my other tools like Mongo Compass Enterprise version, NoSQl Booster, Zoomdata and Robo3t.

Can anybody have any idea why it is not showing? If I use any in-built role, I can see everything as usual.